# Tkinter showing black screen and flickering in latest macos moneterey

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building an chat application GUI for my assignment using Tkinter,
but when i created a basic screen, it's not loading properly, the GUI background is black (not by the color) and nothing is visible, also the button is flickering.

Adding the code below. (Its very basic code)

```
class ChatGUI: 
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        #setup window size
        self.Window = Tk()
        self.Window.withdraw()

        #login window 
        self.login = Toplevel()
        self.login.title("Chat - Login")
        self.login.resizable(width=True, height=True)
        self.login.configure(width=400, height=400, bg='blue')
        self.pls = Label(self.login,
                       text = "Please login to continue",
                       justify = CENTER,
                       font = "Helvetica 14 bold")
         
        self.pls.place(relheight = 0.15,
                       relx = 0.2,
                       rely = 0.07)
        # create a Label
        self.labelName = Label(self.login,
                               text = "Name: ",
                               font = "Helvetica 12")
         
        self.labelName.place(relheight = 0.2,
                             relx = 0.1,
                             rely = 0.2)

                             # create a entry box for
        # tyoing the message
        self.entryName = Entry(self.login,
                             font = "Helvetica 14",)
         
        self.entryName.place(relwidth = 0.4,
                             relheight = 0.12,
                             relx = 0.35,
                             rely = 0.2)
         
        # set the focus of the cursor
        self.entryName.focus()
         
        # create a Continue Button
        # along with action
        self.go = Button(self.login,
                         text = "CONTINUE",
                         font = "Helvetica 14 bold",
                         command = lambda: self.goAhead(self.entryName.get()))
         
        self.go.place(relx = 0.4,
                      rely = 0.55)
        self.Window.mainloop()


    def goAhead(self, name):
        pass
```

Attaching the screenshot below:
[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbLTx.png)

Comment: Why do you create a main window and  then withdraw it

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria i'm new to tkinter sdk, i'm following this tutorial, is it wrong.

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gui-chat-application-using-tkinter-in-python/

Comment: can anyone comment on this, i'm kind of blocked here.

Comment: Do a basic  tutorial on tkinter first

Comment: Even the basic tutorial has the same issue, something fishy with the combination of tkinter and new Mac OS Monterey